# How to pass Vector/Array to a symbolic function?

Tags: matlab

I would like to pass an array or a vector to a symbolic function like this:

```
syms x y
rosenbrock(x, y) = 100 * (y - x^2)^2 + (1 - x)^2;

value = [0, -1];

rosenbrock(value)
```

but I can't find a way to do this. I have also tried to declare the input as `[]`

```
rosenbrock([x, y]) = ...
```

but I'm still getting

> ```
> Error using symfun/subsref (line 135)
> Symbolic function expected 2 inputs and received 1.
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass in an array, then the input arguments to your function need to be designed to handle an array:

```
syms x
rosenbrock(x) = 100*(x(2) - x(1)^2)^2 + (1 - x(1))^2;

value = [0, -1];
rosenbrock(value)
```

With a function like the one in your question, you need to pass in two arguments that correspond to the indices of the vector `value`:

```
syms x y
rosenbrock(x, y) = 100*(y - x^2)^2 + (1 - x)^2;

value = [0, -1];
rosenbrock(value(1), value(2))
```

This question isn't really specific to symbolic math – you would need to do the same thing for any Matlab function.

Answer (score 1):

actually, I ran into similar issues where you would definitely NOT want to have to 
a) design your function to handle an array 
OR
b) pass the expressions like:

```
rosenbrock(value(1), value(2))
```

the solution is this:

```
v = num2cell(value);
rosenbrock(v{:});
```